# CodeBlocks doesn't know the current file

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I am trying to make a c++ program that reads a file existing on the current directory "."
My problem is that when i try opening it from the codeblocks compiler it doesn't work, as when i try to open it directly from the executable it does work, any ideas ??
Here's the code :

```
int Min = 0, Max = 0, TestCase = 0;
Min = 4900;
Max = 4995;
for(TestCase = Min; TestCase < Max; TestCase++)
{
    ss << TestCase;
    FileName = ".\\temp6\\SetOfDifferentials" + ss.str() + ".txt";
    ss.str("");
    ifstream inputFile(FileName.c_str());

    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            istringstream ss2(line);
            ss2 >> stringList;
            MyTempList.push_back(stringList);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < MyTempList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(MyTempList[i] == "")
                MyTempList.erase(MyTempList.begin() + i);
        }

        for(int i =0; i < MyTempList.size(); i++)
            MyList.push_back(MyTempList[i]);
    }
    else
        continue;
}
```

Comment: Presumably because '.' is different.

Comment: Check the build target options in project options for what's in the execution dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top menu select Project -> Properties -> Build targets.

Here you can change the "Execution working dir" for your project and the different targets you have. Change it to "." if you want it in your project root directory.